# Which option finds elements based on the driver's underlying CSS selector engine in WebDriver Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, css-selectors, webdriver

Select the variation which finds elements based on the drivers underlying CSS selector engine in Web driver Selenium and why?

1. By.cssSelector ;
2. By.cssSelection ;
3. By.cssSelector()
4. By.cssSelected

I'm confused between option 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium *Java* you write:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("elementCssSelector"));
```

So the answer is:

```
c) By.cssSelector()
```